# DataBricks best practice to manage resource correspond deleted user

Tags: databricks

currently I have some prblem about my DataBricks workspace when an user was deleted and it cause some issue:

1. Applications or scripts that use the tokens generated by the user will no longer be able to access the Databricks API
2. Jobs owned by the user will fail
3. Clusters owned by the user will stop
4. Queries or dashboards created by the user and shared using the Run as Owner credential will have to be assigned to a new owner to prevent sharing from failing
   How can I keep these resource operate normaly ?

How can I keep these resource operate normaly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main solution for this is to use service principals instead of user identity for all production clusters/jobs/SQL queries/dashboards/...

Databricks documentation has a [dedicated article](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/service-principals.html) about use of the service principals.